# Normalizing data in MNIST dataset

Tags: data-science, cross-validation

Assume I am having MNIST dataset (60000 rows and 784 columns), where each row represents the image which is of 28x28 (784) pixels.

Should I normalize along the features i.e finding mean and standard deviation of a single column and normalize that column or should I find mean and standard deviation of single row and normalize the row ?

I have implemented a code for prediction in MNIST dataset using LDA from scratch without using scikit i.e. finding covariance of each class. But I was not getting proper prediction. So I normalized the rows i.e. improving image intensity and it worked, after that I thought to normalize columns (without normalizing rows) and got poor prediction. In a nutshell, it worked when I normalized the rows instead of column. Even I am confused.